# \file_add_path:Nn function in interface3: l3file package

Tags: expl3, latex3

Most if not all programming languages provide a function that returns the full path of the executable, for example `ActiveWorkbook.Path`in `Excel/VBA`, a feature that allows writing code that is immune to where the executable is located in the directory. I am attempting to use the `\file_add_path` function (`l3file` package, page 136 in my copy of `interface3`) with a similar purpose in mind. While `\file_if_exist` and `\file_add_path` show some recognition of a file sitting in the local folder, they do not what I was expecting, namely `\file_if_exist` does not recognize files that are located somewhere else in the directory, nor does `\file_add_path` return the full path to my "executable" .tex file. What am I doing wrong?

```
% filename: MWE-23-25Sep2017-addpath.tex
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 25 Sep 2017
%\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
%  variable declaration:
\tl_new:N \l_rn_path_tl
\NewDocumentCommand\myPathToFile{m}
  {
    \file_if_exist:nTF {#1} 
    {
      #1:~FILE~EXISTS.\\full~path:~
      \file_add_path:nN {#1} \l_rn_path_tl
      \tl_use:N \l_rn_path_tl
    } 
    {
      #1:~FILE~DOES~NOT~EXIST
    }
  } 
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
    1. \myPathToFile{MWE-23-25Sep2017-addPath}

    2. \myPathToFile{MWE-23-25Sep2017-addPath.tex}

    3. \myPathToFile{XXX-23-25Sep2017-addPath.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\file_if_exist` checks whether the file can be found in any location in `\l_file_search_path_seq` (p. 139 interface3.pdf). And you know that there are variables like `\g_file_curr_dir_str`, don't you? Which version of expl3 are you using (date)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'somewhere else in the directory': could you elaborate? Also remember that for TeX we have all locations set up for path searching (`kpathsea`) as 'here': the 'path' is therefore anything to be added to that (think `\graphicspath`).

Comment: Evidently I misunderstood the functionality provided by both `\file_if_exist` and `\file_add_path` and withdraw my question.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth I'll post an answer: it is a useful area to explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this, we first need some background on how TeX systems find files.

Unlike many other programming languages, in TeX we usually don't worry about the path to a file. The `kpathsea` library is used by the major TeX distributions (TeX Live, MiKTeX) and is what allows us to treat the entirety of the installation as 'flat': for example, one does

```
\usepackage{color}
```

not

```
\usepackage{tex/latex/graphics/color}
```

or (on my system)

```
\usepackage{c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color}
```

This concept flows through into 'local' files using the variable `TEXINPUTS`. If we have a 'here' directory

```
- a.tex
- b.tex
+ ----- subdir
+       - c.tex
+       - d.tex
```

we can successfully do

```
\input{a}
```

but not

```
\input{c}
```

as the latter is not 'here', so we'd need

```
\input{subdir/c}
```

However, if we do

```
 TEXINPUTS=.//;
```

then we set up a recursive search of the current directory and now

```
\input{c}
```

works. (The syntax is that `//` means 'recursively from here' whilst the trailing `;` means 'followed by the standard installation tree'. Notice that the latter is what means that everything in the standard tree is 'here'.)

How does this affect `\file_add_path:nN`? The key is that we are *not* creating absolute paths, but rather adding 'fragments' to the start of the path: the latter are set up in `\l_file_search_path_seq`. Back with my 'local' directory example, and assuming a standard setting for `TEXINPUTS`, to find `c.tex` without needing to add `subdir` we might have

```
\seq_push:Nn \l_file_search_path_seq { subdir }
\file_add_path:nN { c.tex } \l__my_tmp_tl
```

TeX (`expl3`) will now search first 'here' then 'here + "subdir/"' to find a file called `c.tex`. If won't find it 'here' but will find it with that leading path, so will return

```
> \l__my_tmp_tl=subdir/c.tex
```

which is what we need: a path which will allow us to use the file.

---

Note that within TeX we cannot get a directory listing or similar, so it is not possible to do a search of for example 'all of the subdirectories of the current directory'. We have to *know* the names of the places to look in. The `kpathsea` library of course doesn't have that restriction (hence `TEXINPUTS` usage), not does Lua (in a LuaTeX-only situation).